# Azure Service-Fabric and DocumentDB message serialization issue

Tags: c#, json, serialization, azure-service-fabric, azure-cosmosdb

So, - in my DocumentDB I may have the following document:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "type": "A",
  "content": {
    "x": 1,
    "y": 2
  }
}
```

That may be backed by this model:

```
   public class acontent
    {
        public int x { get; set; }
        public int y { get; set; }
    }

    public class document
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public object content { get; set; }
    }

    public class documenta : document
    {
        public new acontent content { get; set; }
    }
```

The idea here is that document is a complex object where content may vary depending on type.

Now, - in my ServiceFabric application I have a stateless microservice that reads from DocumentDB and should return a *document* type object when called from the *ServiceProxy*.

The problem in this is that the DocumentQuery from the DocumentDB SDK, uses Json.NET serializer when querying the database, whilst servicefabric uses *DataContractSerializer* for serializing the service-messages.

So when the *content* part of *document* class is being deserialized from the DocumentDB it becomes:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject
```

But when it is serialized back through the returned service-message you get the exception:

> Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' is a recursive collection data
>   contract which is not supported. Consider modifying the definition of
>   collection 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' to remove references to
>   itself.

To illustrate this issue try the folowing code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace jsoinissue
{
    public class acontent
    {
        public int x { get; set; }
        public int y { get; set; }
    }

    public class document
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public object content { get; set; }
    }

    public class documenta : document
    {
        public new acontent content { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private const string JSON_A = "{\"id\":1,\"type\":\"A\",\"content\":{\"x\":1,\"y\":2}}";

        private static string SerializeObject<T> (T obj)
        {
            try
            {
                DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    js.WriteObject(ms, obj);
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
                        return sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return String.Format("EXCEPTION: {0}",e.Message);
            }
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            var A = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<document>(JSON_A);
            var a = SerializeObject<document>(A);//HERE BE TROUBLE
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

How could I best resolve this issue?

Comment: `DataContractJsonSerializer` doesn't really support deserializing and serializing free-form JSON data, just like `DataContractSerializer` doesn't support free-form XML data.  I'd suggest changing your data model to something fully, statically typed.  Is that possible?

Comment: dbc, - Well I was kind of hoping to build a solution that was capable of handling such complex types. The microservice should just query on id and type, where further serialization should be performed downstream by the caller of the service.

Comment: Will the content always be a simple JSON object or could it have multiple nested levels of objects or arrays?  I.e. would a `Dictionary<string, string>` be sufficient?

Comment: It could be multiple nested levels of objects as well. I fail to see how a Dictionary<string,string> could work here, please explain?

Comment: Well, it wouldn't if you have multiple levels.  It would work only for a single level like the one shown in your question, hence my request for clarification.

Comment: Will you be using `DataContractJsonSerializer` to deserialize on the receiving side?

Comment: The `DataContractSerializer` is used by the ServiceFabric message system, and I don't think there is an option to change this, at least I haven't found one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into changing away from DataContractSerializer to a serializer with better support instead? [Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.data.ireliablestatemanager?redirectedfrom=MSDN#Microsoft_ServiceFabric_Data_IReliableStateManager_TryAddStateSerializer__1_Microsoft_ServiceFabric_Data_IStateSerializer___0__) how you'd plug in a different serializer.

```
class InitializationCallbackAdapter
{
    public Task OnInitialize()
    {
        this.StateManager.TryAddStateSerializer(new MyStateSerializer());
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }

    public IReliableStateManager StateManager { get; set; }
}

class MyStatefulService : StatefulService
{
    public MyStatefulService(StatefulServiceContext context)
        : this(context, new InitializationCallbackAdapter())
    {
    }

    public MyStatefulService(StatefulServiceContext context, InitializationCallbackAdapter adapter)
        : base(context, new ReliableStateManager(context, new ReliableStateManagerConfiguration(onInitializeStateSerializersEvent: adapter.OnInitialize)))
    {
        adapter.StateManager = this.StateManager;
    }
}
```

This could be newtonsoft or whatever. Also I believe that the method is currently marked "Deprecated" however there's no alternative, so if it solves your problem go ahead and use it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate it. Right now I'm struggling with how to design `MyStateSerializer` class to use Newtonsoft for serialization. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is that `DataContractJsonSerializer` does not support untyped, free-form JSON data.  As explained in [*Working with untyped JSON in a WCF service*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2010/10/29/working-with-untyped-json-in-a-wcf-service/) the [`System.Json`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json(VS.95).aspx) namespace was added to Silverlight for this purpose, but it seems that it never made it into the full .Net class library.

Instead, in your stateless microservice can do a *nested serialization* where the free-form JSON is represented as an escaped string literal when serializing using the data contract serializer.  Thus your classes would look something like this:

```
[DataContract]
[JsonObject]
public abstract class documentbase
{
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty]
    public string type { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [JsonProperty("content")]
    public abstract JToken JsonContent { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    [DataMember(Name = "content")]
    string DataContractContent
    {
        get
        {
            if (JsonContent == null)
                return null;
            return JsonContent.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
        }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                JsonContent = null;
            else
                JsonContent = JToken.Parse(value);
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
[JsonObject]
public class document : documentbase
{
    JToken content;

    public override JToken JsonContent { get { return content; } set { content = value; } }
}

[DataContract]
[JsonObject]
public class document<T> : documentbase where T : class
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public T Content { get; set; }

    public override JToken JsonContent
    {
        get
        {
            if (Content == null)
                return null;
            return JToken.FromObject(Content);
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null || value.Type == JTokenType.Null)
                Content = null;
            else
                Content = value.ToObject<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

Then the JSON generated by `SerializeObject<document>(A)` will look like:

```
{
   "content":"{\"x\":1,\"y\":2}",
   "id":1,
   "type":"A"
}
```

Then, on the receiving system, you can deserialize to a `document` using the data contract serializer, then query the deserialized `JToken JsonContent` with [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm).  Alternatively, if the receiving system knows to expect a `document<acontent>` it can deserialize the data contract JSON as such, since `document` and `document<T>` have identical data contracts.